# git diff showing deletes as new changes

Tags: git, commit

Every time I do a `git diff`, despite lot of commits since the first one, it keeps on giving me these old changes that were committed long time ago to do with file deletions.

I deleted an entire folder of stuff in a commit about 7 commits ago, and still on branch or merge, git acts like the deletion is new.  Doing `git diff` still shows every line of the deleted files as "just having been deleted", as if this is new, but I deleted them many commits ago.

What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How are you adding files to your index? `git add .` won't add deleted files to your index, you've got to either use `git add -u` or `git rm filename.txt`

Comment: Or my favorite, "git commit -a ...", which just does what I want, most of the time. :)  And "git status" is your friend.

Comment: It's a good habit to *always* check what `git status` has to say before you actually do your commits.

Comment: I consider `git add .` and `git status` to be pretty much one command, since I always use them together.